# Confusion about flight timing - Turkish airline

Tags: air-travel, airlines, turkey, timezones

I am really confused with timings on ticket.

I have my friend coming from USA to Pakistan, and I have to pick him from airport.

I want to know when he will arrive in Pakistan according to Pakistan time?

[image]

It says that he will arrive at **04:55 AM, 11,Feb**. But it does not make sense,  because **23:10, 10,Feb Washington time (Departure)** = **09:10 AM, 11,Feb PKT** and ticket says flight will arrive at **07:55, 11,Feb PKT**, how can someone arrive before boarding on? :P

Can someone tell me when flight will arrive at airport in Pakistan? I am confused because time and date written does not make sense to me.

Comment: BTW arriving before boarding is easy if you cross the dateline - I left New Zealand Aug 9th last year and landed in the Cook Islands Aug 8th.

Comment: Yeah I am aware of that, but I am talking about `arriving before boarding` according to Pakistan time is not possible, See my words `because 23:10, 10,Feb Washington time (Departure) = 09:10 AM, 11,Feb PKT (arriving time)` in my question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's how that flight looks on the Turkish airlines web site:

[image]

It will leave late tonight (Washington time), and then land in and leave Istanbul on afternoon/evening of the 11th (Istanbul time) and then arrive in Pakistan at about 5am Pakistan time. But that will the be the 12th.

Does that make more sense to you?

Answer (score 7):

The date shown for each flight is the departure date, not the arrival date.

Flight TK8 from Washington Dulles to Istanbul departs on February 10th at 23:10 (11:10pm) and arrives in Istanbul on February 11th at 16:15 (4:15pm).

Flight TK740 from Istanbul to Islamabad (with a stop in Baku, Azerbaijan) departs on February 11th at 18:15 (6:15pm) and arrives in Islamabad on February 12th at 4:55 (4:55am).

Comment: These times you mention are relative to which timezone/location ?

Comment: Flight time are always in local time of the airport in question, unless explicitly stated otherwise.

Comment: Yes I know that, it was more for the OP :)

Comment: date should have also mentioned there as 12 Feb for arrival in Islamabad ... Isnt it?

Comment: @Umair Here it is implicit that the flight arrives the next day, since it can't arrive before it left. ;) This is usually indicated explicitly, however.

Comment: @fkraiem Many flights do arrive "before" they leave, specifically those that cross the international date line in an easterly direction. eg, United Airlines Sydney to Los Angeles leaves at 11:30am, and arrives at 6:30am the same day, despite being a 14 hour flight!

Comment: @fkraiem Yes I am aware of time changes across the world, I was talking about `23:10, 10,Feb Washington time (Departure) = 09:10 AM, 11,Feb PKT (arriving time)` So I was curious how they can arrive before departing according to Pakistan time :P

Answer (score 3):

**Times on flights are always given in the local time of the place the time refers to.** (There may be exceptions to this but I'm not aware of any.)

So, the first flight leaves Washington at 2310 Washington time (EST, GMT-5) and arrives in Istanbul at 1615 Istanbul time (EET, GMT+2).  It is confusing that the ticket doesn't explicitly say that the arrival in Istanbul is the day after departure from Washington, but it is.

This can sometimes lead to flights looking very strange: a short flight that crosses a timezone boundary can be listed as, for example, departing at 1300 and arriving at 1245.